# Web scraping in fctables.com

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

How can I parse 'Match' - 'Corners Wide' in https://www.fctables.com/spain/liga-bbva/2019_2020/ without Selenium? Is that possible? Any suggestion?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://www.fctables.com/spain/liga-bbva/2019_2020/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
req = driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#privacy-optin > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.panel-body > div.btn.btn-lg.btn-block.btn-success').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/20);")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#table_28733 > div.panel-body.pn > div.table_menu > ul > li:nth-child(5)').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#table_28733 > div.panel-body.pn > div.table_menu > ul > li.tab.open > ul > li:nth-child(3)').click()

body = driver.execute_script("return document.body")
source = body.get_attribute('innerHTML') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to load `Match->Corners wide` table to DataFrame:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.fctables.com/spain/liga-bbva/2019_2020/'
corners_wide_url = 'https://www.fctables.com/xml/table_type/?id={sid}&template={tid}&type=game_stats&type2=corners_wide&lang_id=2&short='
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
sid = soup.select_one('[data-sid]')['data-sid']
tid = soup.select_one('[data-tid]')['data-tid']

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(corners_wide_url.format(sid=sid, tid=tid)).text)[0].droplevel(0, axis=1)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     #             Team Corners  ...         Average corners per game        
     #             Team     For  ... Against                      For Against
0    1          Sevilla   135.0  ...   136.0                     5.84    3.58
1    2      Real Madrid   111.0  ...   143.0                     5.00    3.76
2    3        Barcelona   101.0  ...   137.0                     4.87    3.61
3    4            Eibar   105.0  ...   185.0                     4.84    4.87
4    5          Levante    88.0  ...   211.0                     4.76    5.55
5    6  Atletico Madrid   102.0  ...   177.0                     4.76    4.66
6    7       Real Betis   101.0  ...   198.0                     4.74    5.21
7    8    Real Sociedad   111.0  ...   146.0                     4.68    3.84
8    9           Getafe    98.0  ...   126.0                     4.66    3.32
9   10  Athletic Bilbao    95.0  ...   171.0                     4.63    4.50
10  11          Osasuna    92.0  ...   170.0                     4.61    4.47
11  12       Celta Vigo    93.0  ...   205.0                     4.53    5.39
12  13         Mallorca    89.0  ...   175.0                     4.37    4.61
13  14          Granada    92.0  ...   177.0                     4.24    4.66
14  15         Valencia    83.0  ...   171.0                     4.18    4.50
15  16       Valladolid    85.0  ...   190.0                     4.16    5.00
16  17         Espanyol    76.0  ...   165.0                     4.08    4.34
17  18          Leganes    79.0  ...   151.0                     4.00    3.97
18  19       Villarreal    69.0  ...   219.0                     3.71    5.76
19  20           Alaves    75.0  ...   176.0                     3.58    4.63

[20 rows x 14 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Marvelous. Thank you. And how did you get that url: "corners_wide_url"?

Comment: @EnriqueRamirezMoreno I found this URL in Firefox Developer Tools->Network Tab. This is the URL that the page connects to to get the info about the `corners_wide`